# what does RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS request in android in app billing return?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Hi I just want to know whether the RESTORE_TRANSACTIONS request for android in app billing returns all the purchased items for all the apps the user has bought or just the ones from that specific application?

Answer (score 0):

Just the purchases for that specific app.  It raises a PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED event just as if the user had made a new in-app purchase in your app.  If the user makes a purchase in another app, your app won't be notified either.  Same logic.